# Drag & Drop from/to multiple listboxes in WPF using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, drag-and-drop, listbox

I have `ListBoxes` I create dynamically (according to the number of teams in DB).
Each `ListBox` contains User objects.
I want to be able to drag and drop users from one `ListBox` to another. All the examples I could find were to drag and drop from one predefined source list to another predefined target `ListBox`.

How this can be implemented?

Comment: Here is  a sample application for drag and drop http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/drag-and-drop-item-in-listbox-in-wpf/

Comment: This sample is for two predefined lists, and the mechanism works in one way direction. i need multiple list with two way direction

Comment: Just mirror the functionality for other list, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to test this right now, but could you try attaching the events from Joby's link to your dynamically created ListBoxes? It would look something like:

```
// Create an instance of the control
var control = Activator.CreateInstance(ListBox);

control.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += ListBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown;
control.Drop += ListBox_Drop;
```

For completeness, in case the source link disappears, here are the event handlers from http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/drag-and-drop-item-in-listbox-in-wpf/

```
ListBox dragSource = null;
private void ListBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   ListBox parent = (ListBox)sender;
   dragSource = parent;
   object data = GetDataFromListBox(dragSource, e.GetPosition(parent));

   if (data != null)
   {
      DragDrop.DoDragDrop(parent, data, DragDropEffects.Move);
   }
}

#region GetDataFromListBox(ListBox,Point)
private static object GetDataFromListBox(ListBox source, Point point)
{
    UIElement element = source.InputHitTest(point) as UIElement;
    if (element != null)
    {
       object data = DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
       while (data == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
       {
           data = source.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer(element);
           if (data == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
           {
              element = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element) as UIElement;
           }
           if (element == source)
           {
              return null;
           }
        }
        if (data != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
        {
           return data;
        }
     }

     return null;
 }

#endregion

private void ListBox_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
   ListBox parent = (ListBox)sender;
   object data = e.Data.GetData(typeof(string));
   ((IList)dragSource.ItemsSource).Remove(data);
   parent.Items.Add(data);
}
```